# Including Boost libraries into standard MinGW path

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

how can I include Boost libraries (together with its includes files) in the standard search path of MinGW so that I can just do something like this;

```
#include <filesystem.hpp>
using boost::filesystem;
```

and avoiding adding -I, -l, and -L in Makefile, just like C++ standard library?
(I'm using compiled boost 1.51.0 on Windows 7)

Comment: Anything keeping you from simply copying it into default include dir (`<mingwdir>\include`) or library dir (`<mingwdir>\lib` iirc)?

Comment: @Grizzly I was worrying messing up with my MinGW lib folder but then I'm going to try that.

Comment: works fine for me. What exactly did you put where? (Note that you obviously still need -l for the appropriate libraries, this will just give you the paths)

Comment: @Grizzly: I copied all the libs into the lib folder of MinGW and the boost folder into the include folder of MinGW. My intention is to avoid all the -I, -l, -L in the Makefile or any build infrastructure.

Comment: @Grizzly: how exactly did you do, and what were your compiling commands?

Comment: I have my headers in `<mingwdir>/include/boost` since I include as `boost/...` and libs in `<mingwdir>/lib` and compile something like `g++ -o test.exe main.cpp -lboost_thread`. Since I'm using dynamiccally linked boost libs I additionally need the dll to be somewhere where it can be found, but it should also work with statically linked libs. Avoiding `-l` for the lib is somewhat problematic, since you'd have to always link all boost libraries in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default GCC looks for C_INCLUDE_PATH and CPP_INCLUDE_PATH environment variables.
Instead of doing -I, you can add the following to your .bashrc:

```
export CPP_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/your/boost/header
```

Comment: searched for .bashrc file and found none in MinGW folder. Is that a file I need to write?

Comment: @Amani: It's a Linux file, which you obviously don't have for Windows. In Windows you add environment variables via the Control Panel.

Comment: @pwned It always depends on the fact if you use MSys or not. There are a few people that use MinGW with cmd... But you can always use the vcvars.bat trick, though.

Comment: @pwned: my Msys folder is withing MinGW folder and still can not find the .bashrc.

Comment: @Amani you can add the file yourself, msys will export the variables when it is restarted

Comment: @pwned: I created a "my.bashrc" in C:\MinGW\msys\1.0 and with CPP_INCLUDE_PATH=C:\MinGW_local\boost\include and get permission denies when compiling my program. I'm trying to figure out how to give permission without success so far.

Comment: [GCC docs says](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html) that it's **CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH**

Comment: I have typed "set CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=D:\boost_1_62_0" in command line and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The way I do it (for `/usr/local`) I add to my globally defined `CXXFLAGS`. I always use MinGW in conjunction with MSys. I changed the fstab (`C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc\fstab`) to map `C:\Users` to `/home`. (That should be the default anyway.) Then I define a `.profile` file in my user directory that contains my "default" `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`. So in my case:

```
export CFLAGS=-g -Wall -I/usr/local/include
export CXXFLAGS=-g -Wall -I/usr/local/include
export LDFLAGS=/usr/local/lib
```

In the makefile, I then only extend the variables as needed:

```
LDFLAGS += -lawsomelib
```

This works like a charm and has the advantage that I can locally redefine `CXXFLAGS` in special cases. Basically you should assume in a makefile that the variables CC, CXX, CXXFLAGS, CFLAGS and LDFLAGS are already defined and contain useful stuff. This is the portable and sort of standard way to do it.

(NOTE: `/usr/local` is not used as standard include location in vanilla MinGW + MSys.)